# Cardinality of equivalence relations of $\mathbb R$ with 2 equivalence classes.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

1. Cardinality of equivalence relations of $\mathbb R$ with 2 equivalence classes.

$2.$ Cardinality of equivalence relations of $\mathbb R$ with $\aleph_{0}$ equivalence classes.

**My solution:**

$1. \text{Answer :} 2^\aleph.$

Exaplanation: Take $\left\{0,1 \right\}^\mathbb R .$
$\text{0 and 1  the are the equivalence classes and each $f\in \left\{0,1 \right\}^\mathbb R$ is a 
equivalence relation so there is $2^\aleph$ functions.}$

$2. \text{Answer :} 2^\aleph.$

Exaplanation: Take $\mathbb N^\mathbb R .$
$\text{Each $n\in \mathbb N$   is an equivalence class and each $f\in \mathbb N^\mathbb R$ is an 
equivalence relation so there is $2^\aleph$ functions.}$

I think my answers are correct but i really dont sure my explanations is correct.

I'd be grateful for your help!

Comment: There is some overcounting in both explanations.  This is pretty easy to adjust for in the first part (you are double counting every such equivalence relation, and you count one "partition" with fewer than two equivalence classes), but the adjustments for the second part are a little harder.

Comment: Sorry, my first comment has errors, but it is essentially right - the correspondence between functions and equivalence relations is not $1-1.$

Comment: I cant see why there are overcounting . Each function is different at least by one value. What i'm missing ?

Comment: By $\aleph$ with no suffix, do you mean $\mathfrak c,$ the cardinality of the real line?

Comment: Two different functions determine the same equivalence relation. @erez

Comment: Also, constant functions correspond to equivalence relations with one equivalence class, so you need to consider only onto functions, modulo permutations of the codomain $\{0,1\}$ and $\mathbb N.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix $(1),$ you can put $0$ in equivalence class $0.$ Then every equivalence relation with two equivalence classes can be put in $1-1$ correspondence with the set:

$$S=\{f:\mathbb R\setminus\{0\}\to\{0,1\}\mid \exists y\in\mathbb R\setminus\{0\}: f(y)=1\}$$

The condition that $f(y)=1$ for some $y$ means that we are including all functions $\mathbb R\setminus\{0\}\to \mathbf 2$ except one, the constant zero function. But an infinite set minus a single element had the same cardinality has the original elements.

And since $|\mathbb R\setminus \{0\}|=|\mathbb R|=\mathfrak c,$
$$|S|=2^{\mathfrak c}.$$

---

Question (2) is harder to fix.

To fix (2), first note that:

$$\mathbb N^{\mathfrak c}\leq \left(2^{\aleph_0}\right)^{\mathfrak c}=2^{\aleph_0\times\mathfrak c}=2^{\mathfrak c}\leq \mathbb N^{\mathfrak c}.\tag3$$

So your answer is equal to $2^{\mathfrak c}.$

You’ve shown it is an upper bound on the cardinality.

Specifically, you shown a subset of a set with cardinality $2^{\mathfrak c}$ has an onto map to the set of equivalence relations.

Show it is also a lower bound on the cardinality, by taking any $f:\mathbb R\setminus \mathbb N\to \{0,1\}$ with $f(-1)=0,$ and defining an equivalence relation $x\sim y$ on $\mathbb R$ if ($x,y\in \mathbb R\setminus \mathbb N$ and $f(x)=f(y)$) or if $x=y\in\mathbb N.$

Two different functions give two different equivalence relations with countably many equivalence classes, so this is a subset of our desired set of cardinality $2^{\mathfrak c}.$

---

$(3)$ works for any cardinalities. With $1<\mathfrak  a\leq2^{\mathfrak b}$ and $\mathfrak b$ infinite, then:

$$\mathfrak a^{\mathfrak b}=2^{\mathfrak b}$$