# Equivalence-relations overcounting

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I posted this [Cardinality of equivalence relations of $\mathbb R$ with 2 equivalence classes.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4261065/cardinality-of-equivalence-relations-of-mathbb-r-with-2-equivalence-classes) but cant understand some important things.

In general, lets say i want to find the cardinality of equivalence relations of $\mathbb R$ with $x\in \mathbb N$ equivalence classes.

Take $x^\mathbb R$ , i cant understand why there are overcounting ?

Suppose $x=\left\{0,1 \right\}$ then $|x|=2.$

Define:

$A:=\left\{\text{The constant zero function }\right\}$,
$B:=\left\{\text{The constant one function }\right\}.$

$A,B$ are equivalence-relations with $1$ equivalence class.

I cant understand why there are equivalence-relations overcounting and the cardinality is not just $|x^\mathbb R \setminus A \cup B.|$

I'd be grateful for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct that there is overcounting if we look at the set of all functions.

Each function $f:\Bbb R\to X$ defines an equivalence relation $r\sim r'\Leftrightarrow f(r)=f(r')$, but if $f$ is not **surjective**, then there may be less than $|X|$ equivalence classes. If we're only counting equivalence relations with exactly $|X|$ many equivalence classes, then we should only count surjective functions.

---

It turns out, though, that the number of functions $\Bbb R\to X$ is equal to the number of surjections $\Bbb R\to X$ for any $|X|\leq |\Bbb R|$.

First, clearly every surjection is a function, so if we can show that each function can define a unique surjection, then we've proven that the set of functions and the set of surjections have equal cardinality.

Since $|X|\leq |\Bbb R|$, there exists a surjection $h:\Bbb R_{\leq 0}\to X$ surjecting the non-positive real numbers onto $X$. Let $f:\Bbb R\to X$ be a function, and define $g_f:\Bbb R_{>0}\to X$ as $g_f(r)=f(\ln(r))$. Finally, combining $h$ and $g_f$ gives a surjection $h\cup g_f:\Bbb R\to X$.

If $f\neq f'$, then also $g_f\neq g_{f'}$, and thus $h\cup g_f\neq h\cup g_{f'}$. This shows that each function $\Bbb R\to X$ can define a unique surjection $\Bbb R\to X$.

Comment: So if i take $X:=\left\{ 0,1,2 \right\} \implies |X|=3$ ,      Define $C:=\left\{ f\in X^\mathbb R | imf= \left\{ 0,1,2 \right\} \right\}$ each $f \in C$ is a unique equivalence-relation (unique function) ? Thanks !

Comment: Not really; $f\in C$ is not an equivalence relation, it's just a function. But each $f\in C$ defines a unique equivalence relation $\sim_f$ as $r\sim_f r'$ iff $f(r)=f(r')$. You should check that $\sim_f$ is an equivalence relation (i.e., that it is reflexive, transitive and symmetric) and that if $f,f'\in C$ and $f\neq f'$, then ${\sim_f}\neq {\sim_{f'}}$.